# How to get the correct state in an useEffect hook, after another useEffect hook modifies the same state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two `useEffect` hooks, which will both run on change in `startTime/endTime` state.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedProduct) {
        fetch(...)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => setMyState(res.data));
    }
}, [selectedProduct, startTime, endTime]);

useEffect(() => {
    if(selectedStep){
        console.log(myState); //this runs twice, once for the old state and once for the new state, after above useEffect's setState is complete
    }
}, [selectedStep, startTime, endTime, myState]);
```

I understand from looking around that this is probably because React does some sort of batching for performance gain such that `setState` is async in nature. Also, the `fetch` call would be async too, so it will take time to set the new state.

From what I have searched, I see that there is `a callback` for `class based` React components using `setState` but as I am using hooks, I am not sure what to do. I can move the second `useEffect` code in the first one, but that would require some ugly `if-else` conditions as I need to check if `selectedStep` has not changed, and then I can use the `res.data` directly.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not batching of operations or anything like that, it's just that that's how it works: When `startTime` or `endTime` changes, each of those hooks is executed, and since the first changes `myState`, your second one gets called again for that change.

A few options for you

1. Combine the hooks as you described, even if it involves conditional logic.
2. Depending on what you're doing with `myState`, you might make the second hook use the callback form of `setMyState` which receives the current state value as a parameter.
3. (If possible) Remove the dependencies on other state items in your second `useEffect` so that it only gets executed when `myState` changes

Despite your saying it'll involve some `if`/`else`, I'd lean toward #1 if you can't do #3.

Comment: I guess I don't mind the `if-else` that much either, but wouldn't it require me to keep an extra state to check if `selectedProduct` has changed? Because if it has, then I want to make the `fetch` call, if it hasn't and `startTime and endTime` haven't changed either, I don't (suppose `selectedStep` has changed).

Comment: @ShubhamDhingra - I think I'd probably move the `fetch` out of there anyway into its own function and then call that function A) on mount, and B) when I'm changing `selectedProduct` (rather than using `useEffect` to do it). But it's really hard to say with just a bird's eye view of what you're doing.

Comment: `#3` seems to do the job. I guess I don't really need `startTime` and `endTime` to trigger the second `useEffect`. Thanks!